# @XmlJavaTypeAdapter and wrappers

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, wrapper

I don't want use `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations with XmlAdapter's class in my code directly.
So, I wrote some wrapper:

```
class BinderWrapper<MODEL, BEAN> extends XmlAdapter<BEAN, MODEL>{
    private final Binder<MODEL, BEAN> target;
    private BinderWrapper(Binder<MODEL, BEAN> target){
        this.target = target;
    }
    static <MODEL, BEAN> BinderWrapper<MODEL, BEAN> createInstance(Binder<MODEL, BEAN> binder){
        return new BinderWrapper<MODEL, BEAN>(binder);
    }
    @Override
    public MODEL unmarshal(BEAN v) throws Exception {
        return target.unBean(v);
    }
    @Override
    public BEAN marshal(MODEL v) throws Exception {
        return target.toBean(v);
    }
}
```

that's wrappes my binders like `XmlAdapter` s. All my binders will implements `Binder` interface

```
public interface Binder<MODEL, BEAN> {
    MODEL unBean(BEAN bean);
    BEAN toBean(MODEL model);
}
```

But there is a problem. `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` require XmlAdapter class without any wrapper. How I can solve this problem? - use other annotation / write some config / write some magic annotation /..

Thanks.

**upd**

I have model classes that aren't *JavaBeans*. So I want do some two step mapping : in beans and than into xml. I want do first step with annotations too. Probably I well need this beans not only for *JAXB*. The real question is : can I do first step with some non *JAXB* annotations?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation directly?  I'm not sure what you gain with your approach.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan,  Hm.. I think it will be littered my code.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan, question updated.

Comment: Moving the discussion to an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412601/xmljavatypeadapter-and-wrappers/4412888#4412888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have model classes that aren't
>   JavaBeans. So I want do some two step
>   mapping : in beans and than into xml.
>   I want do first step with annotations
>   too. Probably I well need this beans
>   not only for JAXB. The real question
>   is : can I do first step with some non
>   JAXB annotations?

The XmlAdapter provides the two step mapping you are looking for.  If you look at the example linked below *Map* is the object that is not a Java Bean.  What the XmlAdapter does is convert it to a Java Bean that can be mapped.

You may find it easier to use the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation at the type level rather than the property level.  When used at the type level you are saying everyone that references that class should use the adapter instead of per property.  See my post on [JAXB and Immutable Objects](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html) for a type level example.

**For more information see:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Comment: Ok. I think, I'll help. Tomorrow I'll try implement it.